# Using BeginForm to post form data to an ASP.NET MVC API controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Basically, I have an API controller with the following method:

```
public void Post([FromBody] string value)
{
   Repository.Save(value);
}
```

I construct my form like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", Url = "/api/MyController"}))
{
   <input type="text" name="value" value="" />
   <input type="submit" value="Post" />
}
```

The request is routed to the controller, but for some reason the **value** is always null. I've tried with and without the [FromBody] attribute.

I *could* obviously append a **value** query string parameter to the URL, but I really want to figure out how to post form data with simple types (as opposed to creating my own DTO type).

Thanks!

Comment: When you run in debug and you stop on `return Repository.Save(value)` (is `Save` a void too?), what is the value of `value`?

Comment: The Save method returns an int. The value parameter is always null.

Comment: And your code compiles? Because when your method is a void, you should only return a void if you want to return anything

Comment: Ah, sorry, updated the code snippet (I had cleaned it up for clarity earlier and accidentally left the return keyword). Both the action method and the Save method actually return integers, but either way it doesn't affect the value parameter. :/

Comment: I do not know much about Ajax.BeginForm, but through Fiddler/Browser's diagnostics, could you let us know how the content in the request body looks like? is it in form-url encoded format or json?

Comment: I just tested your snippet and the value comes through. I just changed `Url = "/api/MyController"` to `Url = Url.Action("Post")` but since your method is called it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: It's form-url encoded like value=some string I've entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Web API tries to get simple types from the request URI. The FromBody attribute tells Web API to read the value from the request body.

Web API reads the response body at most once, so only one parameter of an action can come from the request body. If you need to get multiple values from the request body, define a complex type.

Second, the client needs to send the value with the following format:

=value

and not like this:

value=foo

So, if you post your data like this `$.post('/api/myapicontroller', { "": $('#myinput').val() });` it should work just fine and if you would like to send an array of simple types just send the data like this `$.post('/api/myapicontroller', { "": ["update one", "update two", "update three"] });`

If you use Fiddler just add `=John+Smith` to the request body and make sure you have the correct content type like this: `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Yeah, I resorted to using my own DTO type for now, even though I really only need a single string value... The approach of adding "=" seems a bit hacky? :)

My idea was to be able to use the Razor helpers for the form to avoid having to roll my own script for posting the value - it'd make for cleaner UI code I think. For now I almost think using a complex type is the simpler approach?

Comment: @TedNyberg I agree that it feels a bit hacky but it's correct according to the HTTP spec. Yes, using a complex type is simpler and  in my opinion the preferred way to post data the a web api controller.